# Passing JavaScript object from velocity template to Java

Tags: javascript, java, javascript-objects, velocity

I am trying to pass a Java Script object form my .vm file to my Java class.

```
 var createReqFields = {BookName:"Effective Java",Author:"Joshua Bloch"};
```

I am able to see the values in my variable createReqFields in browser console. I am trying to pass this object to my Java class from my .vm file.

```
<td> 
  <a id="saveAudit" href="/bookshop/inventoryList.do?action=saveBookInfo&createReqFields=createReqFields" type="button" class="portalButton">Save Details</a>
</td>
```

I am able to see the control been passed to my action class and i could see few SOPs but not this object. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the string "createReqFields" in your url. You want to use the variable. Even if you just use the variable, though, JS will convert it to [Object object] inside the href and that won't be what you want. What I would do is set the href attribute of this anchor with JS:

```
// html
<a id="saveAudit" href=""> </a>

// JS  ----------------V should be quoted ----------V
var createReqFields = {"BookName":"Effective Java","Author":"Joshua Bloch"};
// would probably change this ----------------------------VV
var url ="/bookshop/inventoryList.do?action=saveBookInfo&BookName=";
url += createReqFields.BookName + "&Author=";
url += createReqFields.Author;

// ad to href
var btn = document.getElementById('saveAudit');
btn.href = url;
```

You'll want to make sure you include your JS after the element has loaded. You'll need to parse the URL and reconstruct the object on the backend.

Comment: Is this the only way i can pass this object. Because this object will be more than 25 fields. It is not a good practice to add all the fields in URL right? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I think so. If you're passing that much stuff, I wouldn't use a GET request. I would use POST from a form.

Comment: In that case only way i could do is using ajax? Should i use only Restful services in Java to capture this object? Or any other way without using Restful services too?

Comment: AJAX could be an option depending on what you're trying to do. But you'll have to make sure you construct the object with valid JSON before you send it. Then it's a simple parse JSON on the backend. A REST service is another way you could go, but I think AJAX would be easier.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will give it a try.

Comment: I tried adding ajax call but i am seeing some errors

Comment: Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Could not load Velocity template for URL [/views/addInventoryInfo.vm]; nested exception is org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "{" at line 113, column 40 of /views/addInventoryInfo.vm

Comment: Was expecting one of: <EOF> "(" ... <RPAREN> ... <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ... <SET_DIRECTIVE> ... "##" ... "\\\\" ... "\\" ... <TEXT> ... "*#" ... "*#" ... <STRING_LITERAL> ... <IF_DIRECTIVE> ... <STOP_DIRECTIVE> ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ... <WORD> ... <BRACKETED_WORD> ... <IDENTIFIER> ... <DOT> ... "{" ... "}" ..

Comment: you'll need to ask a new question for that, sorry :(

Comment: Okies will do. Thank you so much

Comment: Fixed it... Since $ is part of velocity variable itself its trying to convert $.ajax ({ }); in the same way. so changed to jQuery.ajax({ }); Thanks a ton for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

**This question already has a very appropriate answer but I am going to add mine with the intention to contribute...**

Understanding what JavaScript and Velocity are meant for can help a lot in solving this problem.

Velocity is processed in the *server-side* and JavaScript is done on *client-side*.

When you say you want to pass a JS object to java, you want to send it to the server. You could basically make an asynchronous request to the server, posting the data to the server, and then use Java to read it.

```
var createReqFields = {BookName:"Effective Java",Author:"Joshua Bloch"};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '...',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: 'bookName=' + createReqFields.BookName + '&author=' + createReqFields.Author,
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

---

Another way is to post the whole object and use Java to parse it...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '...',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { 
      loadProds: 1,
      createReqFields: JSON.stringify(createReqFields) //Serialize it so that it would be easy to send
    },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

---

I hope that works out.

Comment: I tried adding this ajax call inside my document.ready. But i am seeing the error as below: Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Could not load Velocity template for URL [/views/addInventoryInfo.vm]; nested exception is org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "{" at line 113, column 40 of /views/addInventoryInfo.vm

Comment: Was expecting one of: <EOF> "(" ... <RPAREN> ... <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ... <SET_DIRECTIVE> ... "##" ... "\\\\" ... "\\" ... <TEXT> ... "*#" ... "*#" ... <STRING_LITERAL> ... <IF_DIRECTIVE> ... <STOP_DIRECTIVE> ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ... <WORD> ... <BRACKETED_WORD> ... <IDENTIFIER> ... <DOT> ... "{" ... "}" ...

Comment: Fixed it... Since $ is part of velocity variable itself its trying to convert $.ajax ({ }); in the same way. so changed to jQuery.ajax({ }); Thanks a ton for your suggestion